# Visual studio installation path grayed out

Tags: visual-studio, installation, visual-studio-2015

I had to reformat one of my drives (T:) and change its purpose. I had Visual studio 2015 installed on it, uninstalled it before formatting and now the drive has a different letter (can't change it, other things installed on it). I want to install visual studio 2015 again, but on the C: drive. When I run the installation, I get this:

[image]

The T: drive doesn't exist anymore, and I can't change the installation path to another drive.

I tried some solutions where I had to delete registry keys, but didn't succeed since most of the solutions were for older versions of visual studio. Is there a way to change the path?

Comment: What happens if you change the type of installation to Custom? Also, I can't tell from the screenshot, but is the browse (...) button disabled too?

Comment: Run the installer with /uninstall /force so you'll have a shot at getting the registry cleaned up.

Comment: Yes! @HansPassant it worked. I cleaned it and restarted the installer regularly, works great! Want to make this an answer?

Comment: I had the same problem with my D drive which I erased and the only solution was this: I created again D partition (by shrinking one of my existing partition) with only 50MB and I put there vs.exe and then I run cmd with vs_enterprise.exe /uninstall /force - after that I was able to install vs on any partition I wont.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Run installer in command line (Admin Mode) In folder keep File vs_community_ENU.exe

and put this command

```
vs_community_ENU.exe /uninstall /force
```

Then put this

```
vs_community_ENU /CustomInstallPath C:\VisualStudio2015
```

> NewDrive:\VisualStudio2015

it work for me

Hope this helps

Comment: Great, it worked. Although "vs_community_ENU.exe /uninstall /force" did not fully uninstall all secondary components of VS 15.

Comment: Hi. Great tip. I had to install, run your first line (/uninstall /force).
I got confused by the "NewDrive:\VIsualStudio2015"... which on my case was f:\VisualStudio. 

Worked great.

Comment: Applying this to vs_community__1758346211.1527346351.exe  It says that only one command argument is allowed.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem. I had an installed Visual Studio on a crashed harddisk.
I tried everything above, nothing worked. You should use this method as ultima ratio:

There is a [VisualStudioUninstaller by Microsoft](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller/releases).

1. Download it
2. Extract it
3. Run it with `Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe` in an administrator command prompt

If this fails:
Start an elevated powershell:

```
install-package msi -provider PowerShellGet
get-msicomponentinfo '{777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}' | get-msiproductinfo | uninstall-msiproduct -properties IGNOREDEPENDENCIES=ALL
```

Try again. If this fails, replace the GUID with one of the following:

Visual Studio 2015: {777CBCAC-12AB-4A57-A753-4A7D23B484D3}
Visual Studio 2013: {56E09E41-21B6-4F87-8D60-0787D028ECDD}
Visual Studio 2012: {DB786F13-64A8-45D7-8C03-0E819DF9F7B3}
Visual Studio 2010: {01696F98-947C-4CF9-8BD3-ABE70332FDED}

Sources: [blogs.msdn.microsoft.com](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/heaths/2015/07/14/how-to-install-visual-studio-to-another-directory-when-a-pre-release-is-installed/)
and
[landinghub.visualstudio.com](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-installer-support?campaign=ct!!5BD8D98D05CE485780CFB4C2413F9945#!articles/816-6431-i-cant-change-the-installation-path)

If this fails get an exorcist or/and reinstall your system.

Comment: Worked fine. After executing the uninstall tool multiple times and a reboot, i was able to change the install location.

Comment: I tried a bunch of the other options on this page and this was the one that actually worked for me.

Comment: Worked great. But be aware that this uninstalls lots of stuff like .NET Framework and Microsoft C++ Redistributable. For me this broke some programs that require these things, but installing Visual Studio afterwards solved this.

Comment: This still didn't work. I need the exorcist! Looking to install Visual Studio 2017, with the packages in it for Visual Studio 2015 project support.

Answer (score 7):

I know you said it worked, but for some (including me) it did not. After multiple hours, however, I found a way. Here are the steps to my solution:

1. If you have not uninstalled `VS2015` yet, do it through Control Panel.
2. Run the setup (`ect. vs_community.exe`).
3. If you cannot install on desired drive, keep reading here :)
4. Copy the path from where the `VS2015` want you to install it on (e.g.: `"D:\Programmer\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0"`).
5. Open `regedit`(Just press windows key, type it in, and press Enter).
6. Warning, now you are in the windows registry, be careful or you may cause system-wide instability.
7. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData` Here there should be 2 folders called something like `S-1-5-18` and `S-1-5-21-345634235-23423416487`. Just start with the one with the smallest number.
8. Go into the `Components` folder, and here you should see many folders with numbers and letters as name. Right click on the first of these, and click `Search`. ("Find" for Windows 10)
9. Paste the path from step `4.` here, and make sure that the 3 top boxes are checked (they should be by default).
10. Right-click the first result of the search and click `export`. Save it somewhere you remember, then right-click it again and delete it this time.
11. Run the `VS2015` setup again (`vs_community.exe`) and check if you can change the path now. If not go back to `9.` and continue.
12. If it worked, just install `VS2015` and just remember where you put your saved reg files. If anything goes wrong, you can restore them again by running the file.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Actually, using `/uninstall /force` was the solution. @HansPassant didn't make it an answer but at this point, I can't test your solution. Thanks for the consideration anyways!

Comment: I know, just added it to help, because /uninstall /force did not work for me.

Comment: Neither of these worked for me...I can just keep deleting registry keys and nothing happens.

Comment: How many have you removed? I removed around 20 before it worked.

Comment: I deleted ALL the registries pointing to the application except for one that can't be deleted, and it still doesn't work. WHAT GIVES!?

Comment: Hmm, have you tried both regedit folders (e.x. S-1-5-18 and S-1-5-21-345634235-23423416487)?

Comment: By the way, editing the registry has apparently nuked Visual Studio, so I just reinstalled Windows...

Comment: I have downloaded RegScanner and let it search for the path it points to (in my case "E:\Visual Studio 2015"). I removed 12k+ regedit keys in the compontent folder. This finally worked. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Rob, Thank you. Your solution is helped me.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me:

1. Start `procmon` and run the VS installation.
2. In `procmon`, find the relevant registry by looking for:

   "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\*\Components"
3. Make sure the key you've found was successfully opened (result should be `SUCCESS`)
4. Open `regedit` and find the relevant `Components` folder.
5. Search for the key you have found.
6. Export it for backup, and then delete it.

Hope it works for you too :-)

Comment: Thx. The other solutions with `/uninstall /force` and blindly deleting registry keys in `\Components` didn't work. This worked.

Comment: Absolute cringe that we have to do this kind of stuff to install Visual Studio where we want it.

Answer (score 4):

For me, it was the mistake of installing SQL Server Management Studio 2016 before installing Visual Studio 2015. SSMS 2016 is now based of VS 2015 Shell Core. And the new setup doesn't allow for any interaction except pressing the *Install* button. That way, part of VS 2015 was installed to *C:* drive. And hence, all options to change VS 2015 Enterprise install path failed.

I removed SMSS 2016 and, **explicitly**, VS 2015 Shell Core and then tried to install VS 2015 and it worked with Custom Path and Browse button.

Answer (score 3):

You can use junction tool by Microsoft to create a REAL directory on other partition (e.g. D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0) and make a symbol link to it as C:\Program Files (x86)..., just like the command shows below, then windows will use C:\Program Fil.. as path and the real dirs/files are in D:\Prog...

```
junction.exe 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0' 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0'
```

Download junction tool from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Answer (score 2):

In case someone still has this problem (I had it, since I deleted my partition, on which Visual Studio was installed before):

Open the registry, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup
and there you will find some files. At least one of these files should contain the old path. Delete the file and the installation should work now.

Comment: This was the only answer that actually made sense and worked for me, at least with VS 2019. Unfortunately I am working on a VM and the VM has been assigned 100gb of Hard Drive, and my option was to use a network drive but then I get `Drive P:\User\VS\Packages is not a fixed drive`, therefor I think this is unsolvable. My options are to try and remove some space on the HD, or request the IT to make the VM HD larger. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In case there are other people who couldn't get it to work with the solutions already posted, here's what I did:

My problem was, that I had VS installed on partition E. The harddrive containing E crashed one day, and I couldn't uninstall VS properly anymore. 
/uninstall /force wouldn't do the trick, since the setup would crash every time.

So I took my partition "D" and gave it the letter "E". Now I was able to install VS to the specified path. After that, I uninstalled it with /uninstall /force and the setup finished successfully.

After that I changed the partition "E" back to "D" and was able to install VS to "D".

I hope this helps someone with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but just so you know there are command line switches that are very helpful for this sort of thing. In the command prompt, call your executable followed by /CustomInstallPath then the directory, as follows (adjust your executable pathname, of course, as necessary):

vs_community__e45cb735eddf4e4b9d95904be6e1ba26.exe /CustomInstallPath

Just a heads up, this didn't work for me the first time, so don't be afraid to try a couple times. I left my computer for the weekend (logged out), and ran the exact same command without doing anything else and it worked. Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

In powershell:

> Remove-Item
> Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18\Components\CACBC777BA2175A47A35A4D7324B483D

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33839884/3353857

Answer (score 0):

Not relevent to this one but if someone like me wants to change **Installation location**'s of Visual Studio then

**Download Cache** and **Shared Components** can be found in Registry

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Setup

  [Name]                             [Type]           [Data]
  CachePath                          REG_SZ           D:\New\Path
  SharedInstallationPath             REG_SZ           D:\New\Path
```

Visual Studio IDE can be found in

```
%ProgramData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\_Instances\[ID]\state.json

  "installationPath": "D:\VS\Installation\Path"
```

Keep in mind I used EaseUS PCTrans to transfer my VS installation to new computer, and i have to change the path according to new drive.