# How to change Visual Studio 2013 install directory

Tags: visual-studio-2013

There is a question on Visual Studio 2012 and although it provided me with the hint it does not answer the same question for VS 2013.

Since I don't have enough reputation to answer in that question but have a working answer for VS 2013, I'm going to ask and respond.

Here is the background: I had my VS 2013 installed on drive E:
One unlucky day the drive crashed and I had to replace it. While waiting for the replacement I decided to install it on another drive and the installer stubbornly locked me to the non-existing drive E:

Answer (score 7):

Here comes the answer.
You need to delete a specific registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\\Components\14E90E656B1278F4D80670780D82CEDD

The easiest way to find it is to run this Powershell script found [here](http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2006/07/12/how-do-i-search-the-registry-for-a-value-in-powershell/) (again, replace S-1-5-18 with YOUR user id):

```
$searchText = "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0"

cd hklm:

cd \SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UserData\S-1-5-18

gci . -rec -ea SilentlyContinue |  
   % {  
      if((get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath) -match $searchText) 
      {  
        if ( $_.ValueCount -gt 3 ) {
            "Found:" + $_.PsPath
            get-itemproperty -Path $_.PsPath
        }
      }  
   }
```

The key you're looking for is the one that lists the root installation path of Visual Studio, for example:
C0601145C8F8D393D8B362FAC229AFBB : E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
ABD739EADFEFEFB3890650190C9FD116 : E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
471A0A6B0E3324D329AE45D713C81B94 : E:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\

To my understanding, this will work for VS 2015 also (the key is CACBC777BA2175A47A35A4D7324B483D).