# Visual Studio 2015 Corrupted Uninstallation/Installation

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

I was installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise and sometime in installation, it took too much time in same place and I thought it's stucked and wanted to cancel it. But it also took too much time and I force quit the uninstallation with ctrl+alt+del. After that I deleted installation folder with shift+del as if I'm ignorant...

Now I can't install or uninstall VS 2015 properly. When I try to install it again it quits with lots of errors (package failures) plus installation path is greyed out.

[image: Package Failures]

I also tried to install 2015 Community Version, but it says Visual Studio 2015 is already installed.

Do you know how to fully uninstall it?

Comment: Hi Gunes K, you can try to use the forcibly uninstall command like: vs_enterprise_ENU.exe /uninstall /force to remove the installed VS 2015 and type this command: vs_community_ENU /CustomInstallPath C:\VS2015 to re-install it. If it not works, please have a try with the elevated PowerShell command prompt and run the corresponding commands to filter out the share components and uninstall them, for detail information, please check this similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33491016/visual-studio-installation-path-grayed-out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into using Microsoft's official [Visual Studio Uninstaller](https://github.com/Microsoft/VisualStudioUninstaller). Try following these instructions:

```
Using Total Uninstall:

Download and unzip the zip file to a folder.
Open cmd.exe with Administrative privileges
Execute Setup.ForcedUninstall.exe
Press Y and hit enter to run the application.
If the application ask to reboot the system, please reboot the system, and rerun this application again.
```

If this fails to work, try referencing any of the other methods listed in [this following document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt720585.aspx)

*Please Note that this isn't for VS Code's 2017 documentation, which can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/uninstall-visual-studio). That being said, I don't think the newest docs have what you desire. Lemme know how it works!*

Comment: Problem is, Visual Studio assumes it is installed in D:\VS2015. But there is no VS2015 folder in D or another place. So I can't use Total Uninstaller.

Comment: @GunesK what's the default installation path that it gives you? and are the Package Failures the only errors that you're getting?

Comment: Default greyed out path is: D:\VS2015 and yes only these occur when trying to install only C++ related packages. I've installed it into my laptop without any problem but because of deleting it wrong, it didn't being uninstalled properly and now having this error.

Comment: Anyway, I made a system recovery and installed it properly.